# how to remove a XWPFHyperlinkRun by poi

Tags: java

i'm using poi to export a word file.
it's my source.
the question is that
if the run is a textRun,i can remove it by this method(para.removeRun)
but if the run is a XWPFHyperlinkRun
it doesn't work ..
so...how can i remove a XWPFHyperlinkRun?

```
InputStream fs = new FileInputStream("MY_WORD_FILE_Path");
     XWPFDocument doc=new XWPFDocument(fs);
     List<XWPFParagraph> paras = doc.getParagraphs();
     for (XWPFParagraph para : paras) {
        para.removeRun(0);
       }
     FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:\\testxx.docx");
             doc.write(out);
             out.close();
```

Comment: Hi, you've find the solution? Regards.