# Remove XWPFHyperlinkRun Apache POI

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, paragraph

I have the same problem as this partner: [how to remove a XWPFHyperlinkRun by poi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30771181/how-to-remove-a-xwpfhyperlinkrun-by-poi)

I can't convert my .doc to .pdf because of that XWPFHyperlinkRun element.

[image]

I can remove a simply run paragraph like this:

```
for (XWPFParagraph xwpfParagraph : paragraphs) {
        for (int i = 0; i < xwpfParagraph.getRuns().size(); i++)
       {
          xwpfParagraph.removeRun(i);
       }
    }
```

but hypertextlink don't......

If someone had a solution i will be really grateful.

Thanks, regards.

Comment: Thanks to @Axel Richter for the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35088893/apache-poi-remove-cthyperlink-low-level-code/35101440#35101440