# Apache POI Remove CTHyperlink [Low Level code]

Tags: java, xml, hyperlink, ms-word, apache-poi

Continue with my actual bug: [Remove XWPFHyperlinkRun Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35075174/remove-xwpfhyperlinkrun-apache-poi)

With this code:

```
public void eliminarHyperLink(XWPFDocument doc){
    XWPFHeaderFooterPolicy policy= doc.getHeaderFooterPolicy();
    XWPFFooter footer = policy.getDefaultFooter();
    List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = footer.getParagraphs();
    boolean primero = false;
    for (XWPFParagraph xwpfParagraph : paragraphs) {
        List<XWPFRun> runs = xwpfParagraph.getRuns();
        if(primero == true){
            for (XWPFRun run : runs) {
                if(run instanceof XWPFHyperlinkRun) {
                    XWPFHyperlinkRun linkRun = (XWPFHyperlinkRun)run;
                    ((XWPFHyperlinkRun) run).getCTHyperlink();
                    System.out.println(((XWPFHyperlinkRun) run).getCTHyperlink()); //Here is the output xml showen below
                }
            }
        }
        primero = true;
    }
}
```

Reaches the xml that contains an hyperlink than I need to remove, is there a way to remove that?

```
<xml-fragment r:id="rId1" w:history="1" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape">
<w:r w:rsidRPr="003A2DF6">
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Adobe Caslon Pro" w:hAnsi="Adobe Caslon Pro"/>
        <w:b/>
        <w:sz w:val="16"/>
        <w:szCs w:val="16"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>www.cnbv.gob.mx</w:t> //This is what I need to remove!!!!!!!!!!!
</w:r>
</xml-fragment>
```

Please if someone had any answers I will be really gratefull! Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code should remove all hyperlinks from a paragraphs list.

```
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTHyperlink;

...
  for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : paragraphs) {
   List<CTHyperlink> hyperlinks = paragraph.getCTP().getHyperlinkList();
   CTHyperlink[] hyperlinksarr = hyperlinks.toArray(new CTHyperlink[0]);
   for (int i = 0; i < hyperlinksarr.length; i++ ) {
    CTHyperlink hyperlink = hyperlinksarr[i];
System.out.println(hyperlink.getRArray(0).getTArray(0).getStringValue());
    paragraph.getCTP().removeHyperlink(0);
   }
  }
...
```

The `List` generated by `paragraph.getCTP().getHyperlinkList()` seems not to be correct. Neither a `Iterator` nor `for each` seems to work with it. So I've created an `Array` from it.

**Edit:**

Of course the `List` generated by `paragraph.getCTP().getHyperlinkList()` is also correct for using `Iterator` and `for each`. But I am not correct ;-). If we remove elements from the list while iterating over this list, we should not be surprised if the `Iterator` will be messed.

Comment: I whas like 2 days on this, Many Many thanks! Works good and you save me! Regards and Thanks!